# Còmo puedo paginar los resultados JSON en un archivo PHP?

Tags: php, json, paginación

Estimados tengo que paginar los resultados que traigo mediante JSON en un archivo PHP, les dejo el còdigo;

```php
<?php
if(empty($_POST["apellido"])){
  $JSON = file_get_contents('apellidos.php');
  $array = json_decode( $JSON );
  foreach ( $array as $nombre => $hexa ) {
    $array = get_object_vars($hexa);
    echo '<div style="color:#323232; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bolder; background: #efefef;
    padding: 10px; border-radius: 10px; margin: 5px;">'.$array['_desc_appat'].'<span style="color:#323232; font-size: 13px; font-weight:normal;">'.$array['_desc_nombr'].'</span><br /> 
<img src="cal.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><span style="color:#969696; font-size: 13px;font-weight:bolder; ">'.$array['_tipo_docum'].': </span><span style="color:#969696; font-size: 13px; font-weight:normal; ">'.$array['_nro_docum'].'</span><br /><img src="cal.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><span style="color:#969696; font-size: 13px; font-weight:bolder; ">Categoría:</span><span style="color:#969696; font-size: 13px; font-weight:normal; "> '.$array['_desc_categ'].' - </span><span style="color:#969696; font-size: 13px; font-weight:bolder; ">Escalafón: <span style="color:#969696; font-size: 13px; font-weight:normal; ">'.$array['_codc_agrup'].'<br /><img src="cal.jpg" width="17" height="16" /></span><span style="color:#969696; font-size: 13px; font-weight:bolder; ">Unidad Académica: <span style="color:#969696; font-size: 13px; font-weight:normal; ">'.$array['_codc_uacad'].'</span><br /></div>';            
  }
}

?>
```

Còmo puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Necesitas contar el total de elementos y definir cuántos vas a mostrar por página, calcular el total de páginas y, a partir de ahí, mostrar resultados y enlaces a cada página.

Answer (score -1):

Para poder acceder al valor ocupa $value

```
        $ARREGLO = json_decode($JSON); 

                foreach ($ARREGLO->records as $key => $value) {
$VARIABLE_PARA_OCUPARLA_DESPUES = $value->AQUI_VA_EL_NOMBRE_DEL_CAMPO;
                }
```